# How to stop auto scroll to top in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scrolltop

I have a component structure as bellow:

```
<Search>
 <SearchField>
   <Image>
   <Summary>
   <Suggestion>
 </SearchField>
</Search>
<Product>              <---- this changes depending on UI selection
   <Result>
      <Option>
        <Filter>       <----Here button click auto scrolls up 
...
```

The issue is When a `button` on `<Filter>` component clicked then a `modal` opens but underneath everything scrolls up automatically. I need to stop that behaviour. No idea how.

Since there are too many components, not sure where exactly need to set that up and how?

I was thinking of applying the clause to the top level component ´`. Would it be correct?

**Required** to stop auto scroll up when on mobile.

Comment: You can use a "scroll to top" button on the bottom right of the website, is a common practice

Comment: Also watch your Elements tab of dev tools and see what updates (flashes pink I think), sounds like you could be replacing elements that you shouldn't be. This causes the browser to scroll to the top. It doesn't scroll up by itself. Could also be some modal css or js doing it depending on how that's implemented e.g. overflow: hidden.

Comment: You are correct. I see `<body>` style changes from none to `style="overflow:hidden; position:fixed;"`

Answer (score 4):

On the click event add .prevent like so `@click.prevent="activeNews(1)"`